# html navigation bar with search bar

Tags: html, css

I have looked on various websites including this one for the answer and found no answer. I am trying to add a user input text box to a navigation bar that I have set up and it is filling the rest of the space leaving no room for the search button and forcing it onto the next line.

```css
    #nav {
      background-color: #222;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0px;
    }
    #nav-wrapper {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0px auto;
      text-align: left;
    }
    #nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    #nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #nav ul li:hover {
      background-color: #333;
    }
    #nav ul li a,
    visited {
      display: block;
      padding: 15px;
      color: #CCC;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="history.php">History</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="basket.php">Basket</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('login')">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('register')">Register</a>
      </li>
      <input id="search-bar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <input id="search-button" name="search_submit" type="submit" value="Search!">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

please help me with this issue as it is really bugging me and I have been trying to find a solution for 2 hours now. Thanks!

Comment: When i put it in a jsfiddle it was all on 1 line. I had to increase the screen size, but would you mind posting a link to a live version or a jsfiddle with more than the posted code.

Comment: I just edited the snippet to make it runnable in stack overflow and am seeing the same thing as @floor. Maybe you have some extra CSS on your page that you left out of the question which is making it take up the full space?

Comment: can't add the rest of the code, plus it has no relevance to the question and it only controls a popup box

Comment: all fixed, as @redbmk said there was some css code at the bottom of the stylesheet that was infact affecting the search bar that had the width set to 60% which made the search button go onto the next line.

Comment: As @floor mentioned, you'll run into issues depending on screen size. On smaller screens you'll see the button, bar, and/or some of the nav links extend to the next line. You might want to play around with different screen sizes and use media queries or something to make it look nice all around. Chrome has great dev tools for emulating mobile devices or just changing the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not explicitly specify the width of the text box?

```
#search-bar {
    width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: just tried and it made no difference to the bar at all, I'm a real noob when it comes to css as well

Comment: even if this did work... it would likely break eventually pending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make the input id's as list items and it's all done.